# How To Make Circle Custom Progress Bar with css

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, css

Need help to create a circular progress bar css.

html:

```
<pre>

 <progress id='p' max='100' value='0'><span>0</span>% played</progress>

</pre>
```

That is the [website](http://client-acumenadagency.com/sed/) where i am working

Comment: Take a look at this:  http://codepen.io/HugoGiraudel/pen/BHEwo  and this [link from css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/css-pie-timer/).   Nothing to do with me but might give you a good start.

Comment: 1st time i didn't understand anything in my life.

Answer (score 1):

I use **Progressbar.js** for that because I have to increase progress par based on **video playing** and if you apply **css** on progressbar h**tml component** then it will take lots of time so use this Progressbar.js it will create **Progressbar** using **SVG**

> In your client site  i see there is an **video** which is played on **hover**
>   so now this **progress-bar works when video played**

**See this example**: http://jsfiddle.net/kevalbhatt18/grwkhnuq/2/

**jQuery**

```
var circle = new ProgressBar.Circle('#container', {
    color: '#FCB03C',
     strokeWidth: 2
});


$('video').hover(function(){
   $('#video')[0].play();
   $('#video')[0].play();
   // $('#container').css('display','block');

}, function(){
    $('#video')[0].pause();
    // $('#container').css('display','none');
});

var video = document.getElementById('video');
//var pBar = document.getElementById('p');
video.addEventListener('timeupdate', function() {
  var percent = Math.floor((100 / video.duration) * video.currentTime);
    console.log(percent);
    circle.animate(percent/100, function() {

    });
}, false);
```